# How do I see all of my Facebook "Likes" and, if necessary, remove them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

With the imminent release of [Graph Search](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2013/jan/15/facebook-announcement-graph-search-mark-zuckerberg), I am a little concerned about what [Graph Search results](http://actualfacebookgraphsearches.tumblr.com/) in which I may be found.

Where can I go to see all of the pages/links/etc. I have "Liked"? How can I remove these in bulk?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to your profile page and check your Activity Log. You can filter the activity by type and that should help you.

[image: Likes Filter]

Comment: He's right, actually. Under Activity Log --> Likes, you can see a list of all what you have 'liked'.

Comment: The `View Activity Log` button is located in the bottom-right of your cover image. This is directly across from your name.

Answer (score 3):

Open your profile page and click the link to your likes under your cover photo on the right.
That should give you a complete list to cull. They make you click through to "Show other pages", so make sure to catch any under that category too.